# Solve simple equation over positive integers

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve something like this in Mathematica:

```
Solve[3*i + j == 5, {i, j}, Integers]
```

However, I want to specify that the domain is not just integers, but positive integers, so it can actually return the solution `{i -> 1, j -> 2}`, but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Help > Documentation Center will take you to the reference page for `Solve`. Third item under Details and Options indicates how to express inequalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Solve[3*i + j == 5 && i > 0 && j > 0, {i, j}, Integers]

(*  {{i -> 1, j -> 2}}  *)
```